# Arc length of ellipse in different quadrants

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

This question is basically a follow-up or generalization of [How to determine the arc length of ellipse?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/433094/741141)
Given an ellipse with axes *a* and *b*, and the start and end angles $\theta_{start}$ and $\theta_{end}$ of an arc, find the length of the arc.

I can follow the [accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/433284/741141) on that question, but the solution it gives for finding the integration limits

$$t=\arctan \left( \frac{a}{b}\tan \theta \right)$$

only works when the arc is contained in the first (top-right) quadrant.  When the angles are in other quadrants I end up with negative values for *t*.  I'm at a loss what I need to change to correctly handle angles in other quadrants.

Comment: The ellipse is symmetric in the quadrants. Can you use that?

Comment: @coffeemath I'm assuming I need to do something similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/22068/741141; flip the sign based on the quadrant.  I'm just not sure what to flip the sign of - I thought maybe $tan\theta$, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @coffeemath You even addressed it in a comment on the answer I linked to: *first we need to worry about a/btanθ which may need to be adjusted according to quadrant*...

Comment: $t=\arctan\left(\frac{a}{b}\tan\theta\right)$ is not the length of the arc! It is the value of the parameter $t$ in the parametric equation for the ellipse for a given $\theta$. The arc length has no simple expression, and must be computed numerically.

Comment: @TonyK Yes I'm aware, I probably didn't do a good job of contextualizing my question.  The linked question/answer has the full formula; my question is just about calculating the beginning and ending *t* values.

Comment: @BenV: Well you should make that clear in your question. I read it through three times before deciding that it could not be interpreted that way.

Answer (score 2):

Once the Cartesian coordinates of the *point* in question have been calculated:

$$
(x_p,\,y_p) = 
\frac{a\,b}{\sqrt{\left(a\,\sin\theta\right)^2 + \left(b\,\cos\theta\right)^2}}
\,\left(\cos\theta, \, \sin\theta\right)
$$

with $a, \, b > 0, \, 0 \le \theta < 2\pi$ known parameters, essentially two cases can arise.

> You are interested in an *angle* $t \in (-\pi,\,\pi]$:

$$
t = \text{arctan2}\left(x_p/a, \, y_p/b\right)
$$

i.e.

$$
t =
\begin{cases}
\arctan\left(\frac{y_p/b}{x_p/a}\right) - \pi
& \text{if} \; x_p < 0 \, \land \, y_p < 0 \\
\arctan\left(\frac{y_p/b}{x_p/a}\right) + \pi
& \text{if} \; x_p < 0 \, \land \, y_p \ge 0 \\
-\frac{\pi}{2}
& \text{if} \; x_p = 0 \, \land \, y_p < 0 \\
\frac{\pi}{2}
& \text{if} \; x_p = 0 \, \land \, y_p > 0 \\
\arctan\left(\frac{y_p/b}{x_p/a}\right)
& \text{if} \; x_p > 0
\end{cases}
$$

```
{a, b} = {6, 2};

x[θ_] := a b Cos[θ] / Sqrt[(a Sin[θ])^2 + (b Cos[θ])^2]
y[θ_] := a b Sin[θ] / Sqrt[(a Sin[θ])^2 + (b Cos[θ])^2]

Plot[ArcTan[x[θ] / a, y[θ] / b], {θ, 0, 2π}, AxesLabel -> {"θ", "t(θ)"}]
```

[image]

therefore, known the integration extremes $t_1 \le t_2$, the *length of the ellipse arc* is equal to:

- if the arc does not cut the negative semi-axis of x:
  $$
  \mathcal{L} = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} 
  \sqrt{\left(a\,\sin t\right)^2+\left(b\,\cos t\right)^2}\,\text{d}t \,;
  $$
- if the arc cuts the negative half-axis of x:
  $$
  \mathcal{L} = \int_{-\pi}^{t_1} 
  \sqrt{\left(a\,\sin t\right)^2+\left(b\,\cos t\right)^2}\,\text{d}t +
  \int_{t_2}^{\pi} 
  \sqrt{\left(a\,\sin t\right)^2+\left(b\,\cos t\right)^2}\,\text{d}t \,.
  $$

> You are interested in an *angle* $t \in [0,\,2\pi)$:

$$
t = 
\begin{cases}
\text{arctan2}\left(x_p/a, \, y_p/b\right) + 2\pi
& \text{if} \; \text{arctan2}\left(x_p/a, \, y_p/b\right) < 0 \\
\text{arctan2}\left(x_p/a, \, y_p/b\right)
& \text{if} \; \text{arctan2}\left(x_p/a, \, y_p/b\right) \ge 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$

i.e.

$$
t =
\begin{cases}
\arctan\left(\frac{y_p/b}{x_p/a}\right) + \pi
& \text{if} \; x_p < 0 \\
\frac{3\pi}{2}
& \text{if} \; x_p = 0 \, \land \, y_p < 0 \\
\frac{\pi}{2}
& \text{if} \; x_p = 0 \, \land \, y_p > 0 \\
\arctan\left(\frac{y_p/b}{x_p/a}\right) + 2\pi
& \text{if} \; x_p > 0 \, \land \, y_p < 0 \\
\arctan\left(\frac{y_p/b}{x_p/a}\right)
& \text{if} \; x_p > 0 \, \land \, y_p \ge 0
\end{cases}
$$

```
{a, b} = {6, 2};

x[θ_] := a b Cos[θ] / Sqrt[(a Sin[θ])^2 + (b Cos[θ])^2]
y[θ_] := a b Sin[θ] / Sqrt[(a Sin[θ])^2 + (b Cos[θ])^2]

t[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{ArcTan[x, y] + 2π, ArcTan[x, y] < 0}, 
                        {ArcTan[x, y], True}}]

Plot[t[x[θ] / a, y[θ] / b], {θ, 0, 2π}, AxesLabel -> {"θ", "t(θ)"}]
```

[image]

therefore, known the integration extremes $t_1 \le t_2$, the *length of the ellipse arc* is equal to:

- if the arc does not cut the positive semi-axis of x:
  $$
  \mathcal{L} = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} 
  \sqrt{\left(a\,\sin t\right)^2+\left(b\,\cos t\right)^2}\,\text{d}t \,;
  $$
- if the arc cuts the positive half-axis of x:
  $$
  \mathcal{L} = \int_{0}^{t_1} 
  \sqrt{\left(a\,\sin t\right)^2+\left(b\,\cos t\right)^2}\,\text{d}t +
  \int_{t_2}^{2\pi} 
  \sqrt{\left(a\,\sin t\right)^2+\left(b\,\cos t\right)^2}\,\text{d}t \,.
  $$

Comment: Hmm, I had started down this path but felt like it should be simpler to find *t* using *θ*.  I'll take another look at this.

Comment: I was able to get this to work.  When the arc crosses the origin I had to integrate from $t_1$ to $2\pi$ and then from 0 to $t_2$.